Sitecore JSS Components loading issue - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ItemDetail')
Created one Simple component In Sitecore JSS in Next.JS app but after adding the component in home page it stopped working and getting below error.
Sitecore JSS - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ItemDetail')
     Server Error
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ItemDetail')
Tested complement in GraphQL and Layout services and its working fine
GraphQL 
LayoutService
Please find GraphQL and Code Sytax
 `query GetNews ($v :String!)
{
 ItemDetail : item(path:$v,language:"en")

 {
   
   Heading:field(name:"Heading"){value} 
  SubHeading:field(name:"SubHeading"){value} 
   Description:field(name:"Description"){value} 
   NewsImg:field(name:"DesktopImage"){...on ImageField {src}} 
   NewsLink:field(name:"NavigateLink"){...on LinkField {url}} 
    
 }

 }`

import React from "react";
import { withDatasourceCheck } from "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs";
import { ComponentProps } from "lib/component-props";

type News = ComponentProps & 
{
 fields :
  {
    data: {
      ItemDetail: {
        Heading: {
          value: String
          },
         SubHeading: {
          value: String
       },
        Description: {
          value: String
          },
        NewsImg: {
         src: string
       },
        NewsLink: {
           url: String
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }

  const Default = (props: News): JSX.Element => (

    <div>
 <h1>{props.fields.data.ItemDetail.Heading.value}</h1>
<h2>{props.fields.data.ItemDetail.SubHeading.value}</h2>
<img src={props.fields.data.ItemDetail.NewsImg.src} />
 <p>{props.fields.data.ItemDetail.Description.value}</p>
 </div> 

);

 export default withDatasourceCheck()<News>(Default);

Validated all required setting to fix this but still same issue..
How to fix this issue.
